# How can I run Clozure CL in the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, common-lisp, clozure-cl

I'm trying to install Clozure CL using their [guide](https://ccl.clozure.com/docs/ccl.html#installing), and it wants me to add the files `ccl` and `ccl64` to my path, but they have no file extension and Windows doesn't know how to run them.

I eventually looked in the file and it was headed by `#!/bin/sh`. As far as I know, I would need external software to get these files to run.

I want to know if there is some other workaround for setting up Clozure CL more easily, and if there isn't, what would I need to be able to run these files directly from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that all the scripts do is run the file `wx86cl64.exe` in the main `ccl` directory as long as you're on Windows. So, all one needs to do is add the `ccl` directory to their path to achieve success.

Comment: So  on Windows, one just needs to download CCL and use it. No need to compile it right?